# Python Change Directory Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have my webapp written in Python running on Google App Engine; so far only testing in my localhost. My script needs to read text files located in various directories. So in my Python script I would simply use os.chdir("./"+subdirectory_name) and then start opening and reading the files and using the text for analysis. However I cannot do that when trying to move it over to App Engine.

I assume I need to make some sort of changes to app.yaml but I'm stuck after that. Can anyone walk me through this somewhat thoroughly?

From the answer below, I was able to fix this part, I have a followup question about the app.yaml structure though. I have my folder set up like the following, and I'm wondering what I need to put in my app.yaml file to make it work when I deploy the project (it works perfectly on localhost right now).

Main_Folder:

- python_my_app.py
- app.yaml
- text_file1
- text_file2
- text_file3
- subfolder1_with_10_text_files_inside
- subfolder2_with_10_text_files_inside
- subfolder3_with_10_text_files_inside

...how do I specify this structure in my app.yaml and do I need to change anything in my code if it works right now on localhost?

Comment: I don't really understand why you need to read text files. Do you need to read configuration data? Are these templates?

Comment: no, these are text files that have strings that I want to compare a user-inputted string to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *need* to change your working directory at all to read files. Use absolute paths instead.

Use the current file location as the starting point, and resolve all relative paths from there:

```
import os.path

HERE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

somefile = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(HERE, 'subfolder1_with_10_text_files_inside /somefile.txt'))
```

If you want to be able to read *static* files, do remember to set the `application_readable` flag on these, as Google will otherwise only upload them to their content delivery network, not to the app engine.

Comment: this is perfect thanks. I have another question though, I have my folder set up like the following, and I'm wondering what I need to put in my app.yaml file to make it work when I deploy the project (it works perfectly on localhost right now). I have a Main_Folder and inside that main folder is 1) python_webapp.py 2) 10 text files 3) app.yaml 4) folder1 with its own 10 text files 5) folder 2 with its own 10 text files.....how do I specify this structure in my app.yaml and do I need to change anything in my code if it works right now on localhost?

Comment: I added it as a comment up top.

Comment: @stellarowl12: your app.yaml doesn't need changing; Google App Engine considers all files to be application files, unless listed as static or excluded by the `skip_files` pattern. See the [Skipping files](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Skipping_files) section of the application configuration documentation.

Comment: I assume my text files are *not* static files then? Or should they be? My app gives me an error when I deploy it on Google App Engine and I'm not sure how to debug it. That's why I assume that it's because I haven't correctly configured app.yaml because when I run it on localhost it works perfectly. I haven't put in any extra lines of code in app.yaml and definitely have not designated any of the text files as static or given them a application_readable tag. Any ideas or tips on how to debug?

Comment: I don't think they are. What error do you get? What kind of filenames do they have?

Comment: all it says on the page is: Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

Comment: @stellarowl12: and nothing is logged? Did you look at the console? Go to https://appengine.google.com/, find your application, find the logs panel and check for errors there.

Answer (score 1):

You can package your text files inside your application and then do something like this:

```
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'subdir', 'file')
    file = open(path)
```